# jquery addClass vs .css()

Tags: jquery, css

I have a function where i am setting a background on a click event.
I tried two ways, expecting both to work, but only the .css() version works, why isn't the addClass working?

```
function foo(e){ $("#" + e).css('backgroundColor', '#444444');}

function bar(e){$("#" + e.id).addClass('clickColor');}
```

and the css for clickColor is

```
.clickColor{
    backgroundColor: #444444;
}
```

Comment: it might be because of css rule precedence, once you set a inline rule it has precedence over rules set by class attribute.

Comment: how is both these functions invoked

Comment: that doesn't matter, it gets called

Comment: read more about specificity in [css spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity)

Comment: No errors in the console I presume?

Comment: so the question is whether both the css and class is applied to the same element

Comment: The `bar` function doesn't accept any parameters. Is `e` a global variable?

Comment: your element have already another class with another color ? if yes try to remove the precedent class and then add the new, also use background-color instead of backgroundColor

Comment: typo when i did not include the 'e' for bar

Comment: @bmw0128 "that doesn't matter, it gets called". Of course it matters. It's helpful to see just what's being passed to these functions, why `e` might be appropriate in one case where `e.id` is appropriate in the other, etc.

Comment: what are you passing into `bar`?

Comment: Are you calling `.css` anywhere else? That would take precedence over the class, but calling `.css` again would overrule it.

Comment: This question seems to be unanswerable, the question as it is doesn't show the problem.

Comment: Could you create an example (jsfiddle or something) to show us how each works?

Comment: Here's an example, note that the 'addClass' does not work: http://jsfiddle.net/xDzqh/2/

Answer (score 1):

Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color

```
.clickColor {
    background-color:#444444;
}
```

it should be *background-color* not *backgroundColor*

<strike>It's worth noting that jQuery requires camel casing of css attributes when used as a property, but if specified as a string, you would want to use "background-color"</strike>

^ Correction as per http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: I tried both, and all combos. Note that the .css() works with 'backgroundColor'

Answer (score 0):

Css prefers the inline style to class applied style. The `.css()` applies an inline style and hence it is most likely to override every other rule. The `addClass()` adds a class which has a lesser preference.

Answer (score 0):

In css, would it not rather "background-color"?
In your case, your function contains an error, in fact if you spot the value of e in your jquery selector without quotes, it will not work.

Here : http://jsfiddle.net/zPDpC/2/

```
$('#'+e+'').css('background-color', '#444444');
```